# Migrate java.time persisted as tinyblob to Date

Tags: mysql, hibernate, java-8, liquibase

I am working on some legacy application that is using java8, hibernate5, spring etc. What i am trying to do is to include hibernate-java8 module to enable proper usage of `java.time` objects, without any mappers, converters and blobs into DB.

Now the problem is that i already have some columns defined as *tinyblob* and i can't change column type to be date, timestamp etc because of the data inside those columns. 
I tried to do data extraction in MySql with *CAST*, *CONVERT*, *DATE* no luck there, probably because of the persisted value which is i assume serializable object, because when I cast it to char i get output like this `�� sr java.time.Ser�]��"H�  xpw  �x`.

One way to sort this is to create new columns with proper data types, and migrate all the data to those new columns through java code, then switch logic to work with those new columns and delete the old ones which can be tricky if you have to much columns to change. So i was thinking is there some easier, better and faster way to do this migration between types? 
Forgot to mention that liquibase is used for database source control, maybe there is way to do that through liquibase?

Comment: I've uses @Convertor to access old fromat date columns. For migration I think to do clone entity without convertor. Then just switch new entity with old but specify table names @Entity(name = "table_name")

Comment: thanks for answer, i will read docs on @Convertor. i did something similar created new column with proper data type, included hibernates module to support java.time classes, made migration to read from one column and do proper write to new one, after everything is finished deleted old column and that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i solved problem by creating new column with proper data type, included hibernate modules to support java.time classes, wrote some migration logic to read data from old column and write to new column, after everything is done switch logic to work with new column and delete old column.